# WP filter to alter admin CSS styles?

Tags: filters

I want to change the CSS background definition for #wpadminbar in the new WordPress 3.8 admin themes. I can (and have) updated the /wp-admin/css/colors/theme/colors.min.css file but wonder if there is a cleaner way? Is there a filter that I could use in functions.php to update this specific style?

I found this approach but it is a blunt instrument, replacing the entire CSS file:

http://wp-snippets.com/custom-admin-css/

If it matters, I find the single color for the top bar and left column visually odd so I've manually updated #wpadminbar to use the medium color shade assigned to the background of #adminmenu.wp-submenu style. That makes the top bar slightly darker than the left column.

Thanks for any ideas how I might do this more cleanly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`wp_add_inline_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) function to override styles in an already-enqueued stylesheet:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse127850_css_overrides' );
function wpse127850_css_overrides() {    
     wp_add_inline_style( 'color', '.mycolor { background: #ccc; }' );
}
```

You'll need to find the handle of the stylesheet you want to affect -- I've guessed at `color` but there's no guarantee I'm right.

References

- [`wp_add_inline_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)
- [`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

**Edited to answer questions from the comments**

1. The function name can be whatever you want -- it just has to match the 2nd parameter of the `add_action()` call.
2. `color` is the CSS file's "handle" -- if you View Source of your admin page, you'll see that all the stylesheets are called like this:

   ```
   <link rel='stylesheet' 
    id='the-erudite-css' 
    href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/the-erudite/css/erudite.css?ver=3.8'
    type='text/css' media='all' />
   ```

   The `id` part contains the CSS file's handle, followed by `-css`. So in my example, the handle is `the-erudite`.
3. I know this because I went looking for this ability one day, and figured it out by a combination of Google and [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) searching.  The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is a fantastic resource for any WordPress development you're trying to do. If you haven't yet, you should visit -- and probably bookmark -- it.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Is wpse127850_css_overrides() custom or required as a function name? And 'color' is the admin CSS file name minus the file extension? Appreciate the quick reply. And curious how you knew this...

Comment: I've updated my answer with answers to your questions. (Also, if this solved your problem, please mark the answer as "Accepted" -- click the checkmark on the left.)

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. Also should help if someone else later on has the same question, too!

Comment: Had to make two tweaks:

    function override_wpadminbar() {    
        wp_add_inline_style( 'colors', '#wpadminbar { background: #627C83; }' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'override_wpadminbar' );

The add_action line needed to end with semi-colon and, more interesting, while the WP 3.8 themes have specific names/folders (e.g. Ocean, Ectoplasm), you only can affect them by targeting the /colors folder that holds all the theme folders. Apparently you cannot target the #wpadminbar CSS background definition for the Ocean theme, only all themes.